# REVTeX bibliography author initals

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, revtex

I am trying to get my bibliography in a REVTeX4.1 document to print out:

> Smith, PJ

as the author instead of

> Peter John Smith

(which of course is horrible if you're searching for alphabetically sorted surnames.

My MWE is as follows:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twocolumn,       %   A4 paper, two columns
  nofootinbib,superscriptaddress,       %       
  aps,prb,citeautoscript, 10pt,         %   The prb style of RevTex uses superscript cross-references for citations
  eqsecnum,notitlepage,showkeys]{revtex4-1}
  % Either of the following 2 lines (from other similar questions) don't seem to work/compile
%\usepackage[style=authoryear,firstinits,url=false]{biblatex}
%\usepackage[round, sort&compress, authoryear]{natbib}
\usepackage{hyperref}   % Hyperref likes to be the last package included but putting it last breaks figure references!
\begin{document}
The manuscript elements have been formatted for you with LaTeX. 
References can be included such as \cite{Ehrlich2006} or \cite{Kindig2009}.
Multiple references are also handled \cite{Staal2007, Iwamoto2002,CDCgirlGrowthCharts}.
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{PAPER_JSAE_template_BIBLIOGRAPHY}
\end{document}
```

With `PAPER_JSAE_template_BIBLIOGRAPHY.bib` containing:

```
@Article{Staal2007,
   Author="Staal, J.  and van Ginneken, B.  and Viergever, M. A. ",
   Title="{{A}utomatic rib segmentation and labeling in computed tomography scans using a general framework for detection, recognition and segmentation of objects in volumetric data}",
   Journal="Med Image Anal",
   Year="2007",
   Volume="11",
   Number="1",
   Pages="35--46",
   Month="Feb"
}
@mastersthesis{Kindig2009,
    author    = "Matthew W. Kindig",
    title     = "Tolerance to failure and geometric influences on the stiffness of human ribs under anterior-posterior loading",
    school    = "University of Virginia",
    type     = "Master''s thesis",
    address  = "",
    year      = "2007",
    month    = "",
    note     = "",
}
@online{CDCgirlGrowthCharts,
  author = {National Center for Health Statistics},
  title = {{CDC} Clinical Growth Charts},
  year = 2000,
  url = {http://www.cdc.gov/growthcharts/clinical_charts.htm},
  urldate = {30/09/2010}
  howpublished = {\url{http://www.cdc.gov/growthcharts/clinical_charts.htm}} 
}
@article{Ehrlich2006,
   author = {Ehrlich, Peter F  and Brown, J Kristine and Sochor, Mark R  and Wang, Stewart C and Eichelberger, Martin E},
   title = {Factors influencing pediatric injury severity score and Glasgow coma scale in pediatric automobile crashes: results from the Crash Injury Research Engineering Network},
   journal = {Journal of Pediatric Surgery},
   volume = {41},
   number = {11},
   pages = {1854-1858},
   year = {2006}
}
@inproceedings{Iwamoto2002,
   author = {Iwamoto, M. and Kisanuki, Y. and Watanabe, I. and Furusu, K. and Miki, K. and Hasegawa, J.},
   title = {Development of a finite element model of the total human model for safety (THUMS) and application to injury reconstruction},
   booktitle = {Proceedings of the International IRCOBI Conference},
   year = {2002}
}
```

[image]

How can I make my bibliography authors get labeled consistently as above, without, of course, going through the `.bib` file and renaming everyone?

Comment: Are the inversion of the name order (surname, given names rather than given names surname) and the abbreviation of given names to initials (without periods, right?) the only two changes you want to make?

Comment: Yes. I would like to keep the result a `revtex` file of course.
I would be interested for future reference to know how to include periods, but that's not my primary question. It sounds from your comment that there's something else that I _should_ consider but haven't? I'd be happy with any suggestions you may have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The formatting of the references is controlled by the bibliography style file you've chosen; in the present MWE, that would be the `plain` style. To change the formatting of the authors' names to meet your preferences -- `Albert Bertram Smith` to be typeset as `Smith, AB` -- one needs to change one line in the file `plain.bst`.

- Find the file `plain.bst` in your TeX distribution, and make a copy named (say) `myplain.bst`. Don't edit the original file directly.
- Open the file `myplain.bst` in your favorite editor and locate the following line in the function `format.author`:

  ```
      { s nameptr "{ff~}{vv~}{ll}{, jj}" format.name$ 't :=
  ```

  and change it to

  ```
      { s nameptr "{vv~}{ll,}{ f{}}{, jj}" format.name$ 't :=
  ```

  *Addendum*: If you do *not* want a comma between the surname and the initial(s) of the given name(s), i.e., if you want `Smith AB`, and no comma between the initials and any "Junior" part, set this line to:

  ```
      { s nameptr "{vv~}{ll}{~f{}}{~jj}" format.name$ 't :=
  ```
- Save the file, either in the directory where your main `.tex` file is located or in a directory that's searched by your TeX distribution. If you choose the second method, be sure to update the TeX filename database per your TeX distribution's recommendations.
- Start using the new style by setting the instruction `\bibliographystyle{myplain}`.

When running your MWE with the new bibliography style file on one of your bib entries, I get:

[image]

---

Note that you should probably add curly braces around `Glasgow` and `Crash Injury Research Engineering Network` in the `title` field, to prevent the words from being converted to lowercase.

On a related subject, in the entry `CDCgirlGrowthCharts`, you really should set the `author` field as

```
author = {{National Center for Health Statistics}}
```

rather than

```
author = {National Center for Health Statistics},
```

Doing so tells BibTeX that it's dealing with a "corporate author" which should be sorted under `N`. You may have noticed that the entry is (incorrectly) sorted under `H` in the bibliography shown i your posting. Why is this happening? It's because BibTeX currently thinks it's dealing with a personal author" with given names `National` and `Center`, "von" component `for`, and surname `Health Statistics`. Ouch!!! You may not have noticed until now that something was amiss (other than the fact that the entry is sorted under "H"), because the `plain` bibliography style is set to typeset the full given names, followed by the "von" part and the surname; by sheer luck, this just happens to produce the correct sequence -- in this particular case. If you were to run the unmodified entry through the `myplain` bibliography style, the author's name would be typeset as `for Health Statistics, NC`, telling you rather quickly that something's not quite right.

Comment: Awesomeness. Thanks Mico, you're right about those bracketisations... there are a few in my full document and I'm going through them now.
I went with `{ s nameptr "{vv~}{ll,}{ f{}}{, jj}." format.name$ 't :=` to get a period between authors.

Comment: @sven - To make BibTeX insert periods after each abbreviated given name, just use `{f.}` rather than `{ f{}}`.

Comment: Mico, one followup question: Can you give me the format required to combine first and middle initials such that `John Adam Smith` would become `Smith, JA., ...` rather than `Smith, J, A., ...`?
I've checked the bibtex reference but can't seem to wrap my head around it yet...

Comment: I wouldn't typeset consecutive initials as `JA.`; better to typeset them without any periods at all, i.e., as `JA`, or each initial with its own period -- either `J.A.` or `J. A.`. Which method do you prefer?

Comment: `J.A.` looks best to me (I'm trying to condense a runaway bibliography), as long as there's a differentiation with the next author, like `Smith J.A., Brown P.B., ...` rather than `Smith J.A. Brown P.B. ...`  huh... well I guess the second one there is OK too... whatever is easiest works for me.

Comment: I'm sorry, I've this last comment has a "request changed" from my initial question (which asked for `Smith JA, Brown PB`). Mico, sorry for this jumping around. To clarify: `Smith JA, Brown PB` is perfect. If you've already started testing out for my last comment, that's still fine and thanks and sorry for the hassle.

Comment: @sven - I've moved the answer to your final (?...) question into the body of the answer above; hopefully, that'll make it more likely to be seen by other users of this site. :-)