# Compact bibliography with revtex

Tags: bibliographies, natbib, revtex

My goal is to make a bibliography *that is compact*. To give a concrete example, it could be having the title of the paper, and let's say only one or two authors displayed with their full names (the rest should be "et Al").

I looked at several posts on this website but they used solution which seem incompatible with revTex (I do not find anymore the links, but basically many solutions were explicitly claimed to be incompatible with revTex), and I am struggling to make it work. On my minimal working example below, **I have put on purpose several librairies and command at the beginning, as I need to use them in my actual document**.

I am working on overleaf, so I cannot edit files in the latex directory (sometimes proposed like [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/104266/revtex-bibliography-author-initals)).

I would like the simplest solution to this problem if possible.

MWE: main.tex

```
\documentclass[pre,onecolumn ,amssymb,floatfix,superscriptaddress,a4paper,11pt]{revtex4-2}
\usepackage{setspace}
\setstretch{0.92}
\setlength{\intextsep}{7pt}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{physics}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\title{TITLE}

\author{FirstName Last Name}
\email{xx@gmail.com}
\affiliation{Laboratory}

\maketitle
test2 \cite{example}
\bibliography{example}
\end{document}
```

My bib file:

```
@article{example,
    author = {Firstname1, Lastname1 and Firstname2, Lastname2 and Firstname3, Lastname3},
    title = {{Paper title}},
    journal = {arXiv},
    year = {2023},
    month = jan,
    eprint = {9999.99999},
    doi = {10.9999/arXiv.9999.99999}
}
```

How to make it work?

Comment: How and where are you loading `biblatex`? I can't see it in your code. Compact is pretty opinionated too, what is compact to me might be different to you and others, could you clarify more specifically what you desire please? Preferably with an example bibliography entry like `Surname, A., Surname, B., et. al. Title.`, is that all you want or do you want the DOI, journal name etc?

Comment: @JamesT thanks for your comment. I believe biblatex is loaded through revtex (the code displayed in my post works). For a compact definition, putting "Et al" for more than 2 authors could do the job.

Comment: No worries, it seems that `revtex4-2` uses `natbib` and not `biblatex` from your tag, it doesn't appear compatible [Is biblatex compatible with RevTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/12051) so I will change the tags, hope someone can answer soon!

Comment: There's no simple approach with `revtex`/`natbib`, you should create your own bib style (e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/26582https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/26582) and [ensure it is compatible with `natbib`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/213282/106162).  If you want help further, you'll probably have to spec a few more example bib entries and their approximately desired outputs